# selection.getContent() does not work in Chrome/TinyMCE 4.0 inline edit mode

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4

I am trying to get the user selected content in TinyMCE 4.0. everything works fine in Firefox but in Chrome the `selection.getContent()` returns NULL.
I am using inline TinyMCE mode (normal mode works fine).

```
var selectedContent = editor.selection.getContent();
if(!selectedContent){
    alert('Please select some text first!');
    return null;
}
```

Do you have any suggestion how to fix this?